# MATLAB how to detect double click on tree node

Tags: matlab

I have the MATLAB code which deals with a uitree structure. I want to detect when the user double clicks a node, now I managed to make it work only on node click :(

% Tree

```
function test()
    clc;
    set(groot,'Units','characters')
    figure('Position',[200,200,400,400]);

    root = uitreenode('v0', 'Datatypes', 'Datatypes', [], false);
    root.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Potato', 'Potato', [], true));
    root.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Tomato', 'Tomato', [], true));
    root.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', [], true));

    [mtree,container] = uitree('v0', 'Root', root,'Position',[50,50,150,150],SelectionChangeFcn, @callback);

    uiwait(gcf,2);

    root2 = uitreenode('v0', 'Datatypes2', 'Datatypes2', [], false);
    root2.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Carrot2', 'Carrot2', [], true));
    root2.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Tomato2', 'Tomato2', [], true));
    mtree.setRoot(root2);
    %displ tthe root and its children
    root=mtree.getRoot();
    rootName = root.getName();
    for i=0:root.getChildCount()-1
        childNode = root.getChildAt(i);
        childName = childNode.getName();
        disp(childName);
    end

end

function callback(src, data)
    persistent x;
    if isempty(x)
        x=0;
    end
    x=x+1;
    disp([num2str(x) ' tree_Datatypes_Selection_Callback called']);

end
```

How do I make the  callback be called on mouse double click? Now it works only on mouse node select click :(

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution by own experimenting :

```
% Tree
function test()
    clc;
    global jtree;
    set(groot,'Units','characters')
    figure('Position',[200,200,400,400]);

    root = uitreenode('v0', 'Datatypes', 'Datatypes', [], false);
    root.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Potato', 'Potato', [], true));
    root.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Tomato', 'Tomato', [], true));
    root.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', [], true));

    [mtree,container] = uitree('v0', 'Root', root,'Position',[50,50,150,150]);
    jtree = mtree.getTree;
    % MousePressedCallback is not supported by the uitree, but by jtree
    set(jtree, 'MousePressedCallback', @mousePressedCallback);
    uiwait(gcf,2);

    root2 = uitreenode('v0', 'Datatypes2', 'Datatypes2', [], false);
    root2.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Carrot2', 'Carrot2', [], true));
    root2.add(uitreenode('v0', 'Tomato2', 'Tomato2', [], true));
    mtree.setRoot(root2);
    %displ tthe root and its children
    root=mtree.getRoot();
    rootName = root.getName();
    for i=0:root.getChildCount()-1
        childNode = root.getChildAt(i);
        childName = childNode.getName();
        disp(childName);
    end



end
function mousePressedCallback(hTree, eventData) %,additionalVar)
  % if eventData.isMetaDown % right-click is like a Meta-button
  % if eventData.getClickCount==2 % how to detect double clicks

    persistent x;
    global jtree;
    if isempty(x)
        x=0;
    end
    x=x+1;
    clickX = eventData.getX;
    clickY = eventData.getY;
    treePath = jtree.getPathForLocation(clickX, clickY);
    if ~isempty(treePath)
        nr=eventData.getClickCount();
        disp([num2str(x) ': click count:' num2str(nr)]);
        % check if the checkbox was clicked
        node = treePath.getLastPathComponent;
        nodeValue = node.getValue;
    else
        disp('you clicked outside the tree')
    end

  end % function mousePressedCallback
```